# Custom Control with Ajax Modal popup extender

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, user-controls, custom-controls

I have user control which looks like

```
<div>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Select" CausesValidation="false" /> 
</div>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpe1" runat="server" 
    BehaviorID="popup1" TargetControlID="btnShow"      
    PopupControlID="pnlPopup1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />  

 <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup1" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup" style="display:none"> 
.....
</asp:Panel>
```

I'm using this control on a page multiple times. This works only on first control in a page, other instance of this controls don't show modal popup. I'm also using this in a gridview and it fails.

Any idea what could be stopping from popups to show?

Note: I'm using Linkbutton from user control to trigger popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't BehaviorID supposed to be unique?  I think it is.  If you are using this same control multiple times, then it would squeeze out the others?  Try removing it, and see if that resolved it.

HTH.

Comment: yes that actually solved my issue. I cannot answer my post so was waiting for 1-2 days before i post it is resolved. Thanks